# If a triangle is not equilateral, must its orthocenter and circumcenter be distinct?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, triangles, examples-counterexamples

According to [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orthocenter,_Centroid_and_Circumcenter_Coincide_iff_Triangle_is_Equilateral), if a triangle is not equilateral, then its orthocenter and circumcenter must be distinct. The exact quote is

> Let △ABC be a triangle.
> Let O be the circumcenter of △ABC.
> Let G be the centroid of △ABC.
> Let H be the orthocenter of △ABC.
>
> Then O, G and H are the same points if and only if △ABC is equilateral.
> If $\triangle ABC$ is not equilateral, then $O, G$ and $H$ are all distinct.

Well, it looks like I've found a counterexample: $$A=(0,0),\quad B=\left(1-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},\frac12\right),\quad C=\left(1-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2},-\frac12\right)$$

and the orthocenter and circumcenter both coincide at $(1,0)$, right?

So is my counterexample valid, or did I screw something up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, the orthocentre is $(-\sqrt{3},0)$ and the circumcentre is $(1,0)$.

Comment: Oh, I must have been confusing the terms. What do you call the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors? Is that the incenter?

Comment: @Riley It is circumcentre

Comment: Oh, I see where I was getting confused now. I noticed that the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors coincided with the point equidistant to the three vertices. I was falsely assuming one of them was the orthocenter when they are actually just different properties of the circumcenter?

Comment: @Riley: The orthocenter is the intersection of the _altitudes_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I got that now. I feel really stupid now :)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the circumcentre is $(1,0)$, the centroid is $\left(\frac13\left(2-\sqrt3\right),0\right)$ and the orthocenter is $\left(-\sqrt3,0\right)$.